# IOS WebView PHP Web Page Message to App?

Tags: php, ios, uiwebview

I have an IOS App that, among other things, connects to a web server (that I control, running PHP), and I am trying to detect when the execution of the PHP code is complete.  The page is called back a few times and the web page connects to some other web pages (that I don't control) so I can't just use webViewDidFinishLoad.

Is there some way for the IOS app to receive a message from the PHP application that is being called from the UIWebView?

Comment: Why don't you do all the callbacks on the server and only return something to the app when all is finished. You can then use webViewDidFinishLoad

Comment: webViewDidFinishLoad fires each time one of the pages in the called PHP Code finishes loading.  All the callbacks do occur on/to the server.  When the PHP code has finished working through the pages and getting callbacks the app needs to know about it.  I have tried counting the webViewDidFinishLoading calls, but there are a couple of paths through the PHP code each taking different numbers of pages.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get what you are trying to do. You should not be loading multiple php pages only one. That one PHP page can load a series of php function depending on  the logic you are implementing until it returns what the app is expecting. At that point  webViewDidFinishLoad will fire.

Comment: The single PHP file initiates a dialog with an authorization server.  When the authorization is complete the auth server calls the same PHP file.  Sometimes that authorization process involves a number of pages and other times it involves just one page.  webViewDidFinishLoad fires on every page load.  So, I am not ready to close the WebView until the CORRECT final page is finished loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your web page 'knows' when the PHP code is complete you could try communicating that to the app as described in this [link](http://blog.grio.com/2012/07/uiwebview-javascript-to-objective-c-communication.html)